# Texture offset in atlas to create an animated sprite with NGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine, offset, texture2d, sprite-sheet, ngui

In Unity3d, I got a GameObject with the UISprite component from the NGUI plugin.
So I need to use an atlas with textures, to set the texture for the UISprite.

Now I want the UiSprite to be animated. The different frames are in a spritesheet within the atlas itself.

I learned that you can animate something with a spritesheet by changing the offset.
My questions is, how can I set the offset for the current texture and not for the entire atlas? So far, I can only change the offset for the entire atlas.

Is there a possibility to het position of the textures from within the atlas or something and calculate the offset with that?

I don't know how to proceed on this.
Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to do this manually. The approach depends a bit on the scenario you have. If you want to play an animation once or in a loop, just use a [UISpriteAnimation](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_sprite_animation.html) component (Add Component > NGUI > UI > Sprite Animation).

This allows you to create a certain set of named and numbered sprites. Set the correct prefix, framerate and whether or not to loop, and you're good to go.

But even if you somehow want to control it manually, there is no need to directly work with offsets. By setting the `spriteName` of a [`UISprite`](http://www.tasharen.com/ngui/docs/class_u_i_sprite.html), you can dynamically change the displayed sprite at runtime. So all you would have to set is the sprite's name, and NGUI will handle the rest.

If you're looking to do full-blown sprite animation, NGUI might not be the best choice. It is after all a GUI framework. Other options to look into would be tools such as

- [2D Toolkit](http://www.unikronsoftware.com/2dtoolkit/), which by now also include a UI system
- [Orthello](http://www.wyrmtale.com/orthello), of which there is a free version as well

Comment: I already had a look at those options, but those do not support spritesheets, which I am using. Guess I have to do something like that unfortunately.

Comment: You mean you have an external spritesheet? That is, one not generated with NGUI's own atlas generator?

Comment: Either just have NGUI generate your atlas for you. Or start looking into other 2D tools. NGUI isn't really meant for full-blown sprite animation/2D gaming. It's a UI tool. You can get partially there. But it might not be the best choice.

Comment: I got 1 spritesheet which I added to an atlas generated by NGUI.

Comment: Then I would export individual sprites and add them to the atlas instead. NGUI does not handle external spritesheets out of the box.

Comment: Guess I have no other solution for this :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=2994.msg58298#msg58298

Hi,

Sprite Animation using NGUI:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ys60bEIa2zA

The video demonstrates the following:

1. How to import a sprite sheet into NGUI
2. How to import a Unity Sprite (Multiple mode) into NGUI
3. Create animation clips (Sprite animations)
4. Attach this animation clip to an NGUI sprite.

I hope this will be useful to you...

Thanks,

Vijay

dehinrsu@gmail.com